# Jasper report: Page Column- Column Count 2 - Print Order Vertical - Jump to second Column after Row 5

Tags: jasper-reports

I've been working with Japser Report lately and am facing a problem that I can't get any further with.
The goal should be to output my data as follows in the report

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| value 1 | value 6 |
| value 2 | value 7 |
| value 3 | value 8 |
| value 4 |  |
| value 5 |  |

I created a subreport for this with a column header and detail band.
Under the page settings I set the Page Column to Column Count 2.
If I set the Print Order setting to Horizontal, I can't see the data
output as follows:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| value 1 | value 2 |
| value 3 | value 4 |
| value 5 | value 6 |
| value 7 | value 8 |

But that is not my goal. The data should be output vertically as stated above
Row 5 is continued into the second column.

I would be very grateful for any possible solution.

Thank you.